# Asking the user how much to count by and show all the numbers up to a maximum

Tags: java

So I need to write a program which asks the user how much to count by and show all the numbers up to a user given the maximum.

> Example: The user inputs 5 to count by and 20 as a maximum. The
>   program would print out:

`5`
`10`
`15`
`20`

Here's my current code where I am stuck, any help would be appreciated!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Activity5
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter number to count by");
    int countBy = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter maximum number");
    int maxNum = keyboard.nextInt();
    int answer = 0;
    while (answer <= maxNum)
      {
           answer = countBy + countBy;
           System.out.println(answer);
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a great start! Is there a particular piece that you're stuck on, or an error that you're seeing?

Comment: Wouldn't `answer = answer + countBy;` make more sense

Comment: Thanks, it definitely would. Now i'm trying to get it to stop adding one more time than necessary. Such as telling it to count by 2s up until 10, it will print off 2 4 6 8 10 12. The last extra number(12 in this case) is unneeded.

Comment: That is caused by your condition in the while. When answer is 10, it is inferior _or equal_ to 10, so it enters the loop one more time. You would like it to stop when it is superior or equal, or said differently, when it is not _strictly_ inferior anymore.

Comment: But please note: this place isn't a free tutor service. We help with specific questions. The intention is not that people drop their homework here and "this not working please help" and then step by step all issues are addressed and fixed. One question per question please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `while` as follows:

```
while (answer < maxNum)
  {
       answer = answer + countBy;
       System.out.println(answer);
  }
```

Comment: Beautiful, thanks! Now I'm stuck with the issue of it printing off one more number than is needed. Such as telling it to count by twos up until ten, it will print off 2 4 6 8 10 12. I need to get it to stop doing the last extra number.

Comment: Just changed it, try changed version. Now it will work fine.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks! It's the little things....this would have kept me up all night.